# Initializing Java enum properties with a function?

Tags: java

I have an enum in Java 8 with Lombok's `@Getter` and `@AllArgsConstructor` for using additional properties for the enum value:

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum MyEnum {
    RED(1),
    GREEN(2),
    BLUE(3),
    PURPLE(4);
    
    private final int ordinal;
    
    public String getDisplayName() {
        switch (ordinal) {
            case 1:
                return "1st color";
            case 2:
                return "2nd color";
            case 3:
                return "3rd color";
            default:
                return "another color";
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't like about this solution: `getDisplayName()` is called quite often, thus every call runs the switch-case statement.

Is it possible to add another property like `displayName` which values are set by a function analogous to `getDisplayName()`?

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum MyEnum {
    RED(1, setDisplayName()),
    GREEN(2, setDisplayName()),
    BLUE(3, setDisplayName()),
    PURPLE(4, setDisplayName());
    
    private final int ordinal;
    private String displayName;
    
    private void setDisplayName() {
        switch (ordinal) {
            case 1:
                displayName = "1st color";
            case 2:
                displayName = "2nd color";
            case 3:
                displayName = "3rd color";
            default:
                displayName = "another color";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "which values are set by a function analogous to `getDisplayName()`" why not just have a second instance variable called `displayName` and add that string to the constructor? So that you can do something like `public enum MyEnum { RED(1, "1st color"), GREEN(2, "2nd Color")....`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, that would be a way I could go for a relatively small amount of enum values. If the enum grows in size, I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: Ah, now I think I see the problem. You're worried about the values you *don't* have in the switch statements and how they would go to `default`?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my question :-) Yes, that's the point.

Comment: In that case I would go with a constant for the default values. I mean, if your alternative was to add a call to a method for each of the enum values I don't see much difference :) either that or you could remove `@AllArgsConstructor` and provide your own one-argument constructor that does the `switch` part and assigns the correct value to `displayName`

Comment: @RobertStrauch, not to be picky, but `ordinal` is a terrible choice for that constant field. It leads to confusion because Enums have already a field name `ordinal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not married to lombok I would just provide my own constructor and let it do the heavy lifting

```
@Getter
public enum MyEnum {
    RED(1),
    GREEN(2),
    BLUE(3),
    PURPLE(4);
    
    private final int o;
    private final String display;
    
    private MyEnum (int o) {
        this.o = o;
        switch (o) {
            case 1:
                display = "1st color";
                break;
            case 2:
                display = "2nd color";
                break;
            case 3:
                display = "3rd color";
                break;
            default:
                display = "another color";
        }
    }
}
```

Also changed `ordinal` to `o` as per [@hfontanez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681144/initializing-java-enum-properties-with-a-function#comment117874915_66681144) suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum MyEnum {
    RED(1, setDisplayName(1)),
    GREEN(2, setDisplayName(2)),
    BLUE(3, setDisplayName(3)),
    PURPLE(4, setDisplayName(4));

    private final int ordinal;
    private String displayName;

    private static String setDisplayName(int ordinal) {
        switch (ordinal) {
            case 1:
                return "1st color";
            case 2:
                return "2nd color";
            case 3:
                return "3rd color";
            default:
                return "another color";
        }
    }
}
```

The setDisplayName method may even be in another class.

Answer (score 1):

you can just call the method in the constructor

```
@Getter
public enum MyEnum {
    RED(1),
    GREEN(2),
    BLUE(3),
    PURPLE(4);
    
    private final int ordinal;
    private final int displayName;

    MyEnum(int ordinal) {
      this.ordinal = ordinal;
      this.displayName = getDisplayName(ordinal);
    }

    
    public static String getDisplayName(int ordinal) {
        switch (ordinal) {
            case 1:
                return "1st color";
            case 2:
                return "2nd color";
            case 3:
                return "3rd color";
            default:
                return "another color";
        }
    }
}
```